# Find DE given its solution

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

If anyone could give me a hint from where to start because I can't think by reversing solution...

$$
    x^{3} y^{3} = 2^x - 6x + C \qquad\text{ }\quad
$$

Comment: do you mean a differential equation?

Comment: How about differentiating both sides to get rid of the $C$... Is that what they mean?

Comment: usually when we have a diff. equation, we derive a part from it partially in terms of x and so in terms of y, and if the partial derivative for both are equal we get an exact equation and solve it normally.. but the question is giving the solution and asking for the initial diff. equation

Comment: I'm sure what you are asking about is somewhat clearer to you than it will be to your Readers.  Part of the problem is that the body of the Question starts "I dont know how to solve it" before you've presented a statement of the problem.  Relying on the title alone to bear this burden invites confusion.  The body text gives more space to setup and explain what you've tried or considered, and what the difficulty is from your point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have edited the tag 'differential-equations' I am going that way.(Well ..I don't have any other solution :P)

$$d(x^3y^3-2^x+6x)=d(C) $$

$$d(x^3y^3)-d(2^x)+d(6x)=0$$

$$3x^2y^3 ~dx+3y^2x^3~ dy-2^x \ln 2~dx+6~dx=0$$

$$-3y^2x^3~ dy=(3x^2y^3-2^x \ln 2+6)~dx$$

$$\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{3x^2y^3-2^x \ln 2+6}{-3y^2x^3}$$